# Tamanho do kendo.all.min.js

Tags: javascript

Estou começando com kendo, mas a primeira barreira é o tamanho dele, o arquivo kendo.all.min.js está em rumo aos 3mb, mesmo habilitando o gzip no servidor isso reduz para 1.7 que ainda é bastante grande, fora os demais arquivos css dele mesmo que também é grande e fora os arquivos de layout (css e js) da minha aplicação.

Atualmente estou trabalhando com angular, usando uma lib ocLazyLoad é possível fazer carregamento dinâmico de plugins, mas como eu faria isso com o kendo? Existe uma ordem específica para carregar um componente do kendo de forma lazy?

Valeu à todos desde já.

Marcelo